# How do I traverse a hdf5 file using h5py

Tags: h5py

How do I traverse all the groups and datasets of an hdf5 file using h5py?

I want to retrieve all the contents of the file from a common root using a for loop or something similar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`visit()` and `visititems()` are your friends here. Cf. http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.visit. Note that an `h5py.File` is also an `h5py.Group`. Example (not tested):

```py
def visitor_func(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
         # node is a dataset
    else:
         # node is a group

with h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'r') as f:
    f.visititems(visitor_func)
```

Comment: It's not well documented, but if the visit function (e.g. `visitor_func`) returns a non-`None` value, then the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old thread, but I found a solution to basically replicating the h5ls command in Python:

```py
class H5ls:
    def __init__(self):
        # Store an empty list for dataset names
        self.names = []

    def __call__(self, name, h5obj):
        # only h5py datasets have dtype attribute, so we can search on this
        if hasattr(h5obj,'dtype') and not name in self.names:
            self.names += [names]


        # we have no return so that the visit function is recursive

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = h5py.File(filename,'r')
    h5ls = H5ls()
    # this will now visit all objects inside the hdf5 file and store datasets in h5ls.names
    df.visititems(h5ls) 

    df.close()
```

This code will iterate through the whole HDF5 file, and store all the datasets in `h5ls.names`, hope this helps!

Comment: typo change `+= [names]` to `+= [name]`

Answer (score 1):

Well this is kind of an old thread but I thought I'd contribute anyway. This is what I did in a similar situation.
For a data structure set up like this:

```
[group1]
    [group2]
        dataset1
        dataset2
    [group3]
        dataset3
        dataset4
```

I used:

```
datalist = []
def returnname(name):
    if 'dataset' in name and name not in datalist:
        return name
    else:
        return None
looper = 1
while looper == 1:
    name = f[group1].visit(returnname)
    if name == None:
        looper = 0
        continue
    datalist.append(name)
```

I haven't found an h5py equivalent for os.walk.